# Error message “Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection”

Tags: c#

```
private void pajak_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    t_total.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

the data until 500

Comment: You have a debugger, so use it to take a look at the value of `i` (and `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`) when the exception happens.

Comment: `Cells[3]` will most likely be your issue. You don't have 4 columns

Comment: no just 3 cells, if the data less than 100 it works

Comment: "`just 3 cells`" The first cell is index 0. The second is index 1. The third is index 2. There is no `Cells[3]`.

Comment: Your datagrid row count should minus to 1:
dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++

Answer (score 0):

I see this in the question:

```
 sum = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

Specifically, this part:

```
Cells[3]
```

and this in the comments:

> just 3 cells

That doesn't work. The first cell is at index 0. The second cell is at index 1. The third cell is at index 2. There is no `Cells[3]`.

Try this:

```
private void pajak_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
    t_total.Text = rows.Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2])).Sum().ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Johan you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer.